# Google Firebase session campaign attribution on Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

We are trying to log our user's custom session campaign using the CAMPAIGN_DETAILS event in this way

```
val analyticsBundle = Bundle().apply {
     putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.SOURCE, utm_source)
     putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.MEDIUM, utm_medium)
     putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CAMPAIGN, utm_campaign)
     putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT, utm_content)
}

firebaseAnalytics.logEvent(
                FirebaseAnalytics.Event.CAMPAIGN_DETAILS,
                analyticsBundle)
```

but in the "traffic acquisition: session campaign" view of the firebase panel there are only few of them if I try to filter by campaign name, showing only the 2% of the events compared to the actual data.
Even if I try to search through Big Query with the following query

```
count(*) FROM `db.table.events_20210907`
cross join UNNEST(event_params) as ep 
where event_name IN('campaign_details')
and ep.value.string_value like '210907' 
and platform = 'ANDROID' group by user_pseudo_id
```

I cannot see all the data.
Do I forgot something?